# When i use RippleDrawable with API 10 using DesignSupportLibrary, i got android.view.InflateException error in layout of list item

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androiddesignsupport, rippledrawable, android-support-design

minSDK=10 using **DesignSupportLibrary**.

Im using RecycleView, and in the Adapter, when im inflating a layout view in **onCreateViewHolder()** method and im using **RippleDrawable** in this layout's xml file i got this error.

### logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.LinearLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
            at com.demo_toolbarall.RespondScrollEvent$Myadapter.onCreateViewHolder(RespondScrollEvent.java:83)
            at com.demo_toolbarall.RespondScrollEvent$Myadapter.onCreateViewHolder(RespondScrollEvent.java:70)
```

But when i remove a RippleDrawable from listItem view's xml, it will work so i can't use Ripple Effect.

### list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripples"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### MyAdapter.class

```
class Myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Myadapter.ViewHolder> {

        Context mContext;
        List<String> mList;
        View view;

        public Myadapter(Context mContext, List<String> mList) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mList = mList;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(RespondScrollEvent.this).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
```

### ripples.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/window_background2">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

***If Anybody Give Answer, It Would Be Great and My Honour Too.***

Comment: Ripple requires api21+

Comment: Use this `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` this will give you ripple on lollipop and act as a  selector on pre - lollipop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RippleDrawable added in API Level 21 and unfortunately,This is not yet part of support library. It will most likely show up in future update, but there's no time frame announced.

Luckily there are few custom implementations already available:

```
https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect
https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple
https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView
https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable
```

including Materlial themed widget sets compatible with older versions of Android:

```
https://github.com/keithellis/MaterialWidget
```

so you can try one of these or google for other "material widgets".